# Is it possible to set a User ACL in beforeSave?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

In this case, only the user itself should have access to its own `User` object.
Currently the ACL is set in the Cloud Code `afterSave` trigger, right after the user is created:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("_User", async (request) => {

    const user = request.object;

    if (!user.existed()) {
        user.setACL(new Parse.ACL(user));
        await user.save();
    }
});
```

Is it possible to do that in `beforeSave` trigger (to save a DB write)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the Parse Server code and it should be possible. I was afraid that the default ACL could override what you've set in the `beforeSave` trigger but that's not the case. As you can see [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/288e74688848f067cb1a98a3875296189b66b44c/src/RestWrite.js#L1520) it maintains what is set beforehand and you can actually send this setting even from the client.

Setting an empty ACL in `beforeSave` will ensure that only the user is granted access, because a user is granted access to their own `_User` object by default:

```
request.object.setACL(new Parse.ACL());
```

Comment: Ah right, I though how would I `request.object.setACL(new Parse.ACL(user))` when the user is not yet created. But the user is granted access by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just be sure not to call `user.save()` in a `beforeSave`

Comment: Why shouldn't we do this?

Comment: @Pwnedev It will trigger an infinite loop causing the beforeSave to run again and again.

Comment: @HemangKumar That's true, you should probably rephrase that though, because you can call user.save() in a beforeSave, just not in the beforeSave of it's own class (for the reason you mentioned).